# XMPP server doesn't send any reply to messages and messages aren't sent

Tags: xml, xmpp

I am implementing my little XMPP bot and so far I was able to authenticate and bind. The last XML I get from the server is:

```
<iq id='bind_1' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'>
```

user@example.im/bbe8782c

So I guess that means I succeed to bind a resource. right after I send the message:

```
<message type="chat" to="someone@example.im" xml:lang='en'>
            <body>ho</body>
</message>
```

Both accounts exist and I can send messages from each one to the other using my XMPP client and it looks almost the same in its XML console, but when I do it from my programme the message isn't being sent and the programme hangs on reading from the socket (e.g. the server doesn't send back any reply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one another step before you can send messages, [session establishment](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#session) - it was deprecated in later rfc6121, but old servers may still wait for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a life saver :) I totally forgot that session thing.